# Django sum of time differences from model fields

Tags: python, django, view, model

I'm trying to get the sum of time differences from model fields in Django. I've tried this but I get an empty result with no error:

**model.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    design_start = models.DateField(editable= True, default=datetime.today, blank=True)
    design_end = models.DateField(editable= True, default=datetime.today, blank=True)

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
```

I'm trying to get the total design time of all the projects by subtracting  *design_start* from *design_end* and then getting the sum of everything

**views.py**

```
class DashView(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'project_list'    
    template_name = 'index.html'
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['design_time'] = Portfolio.objects.all().annotate(
            design_time = ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('projects__design_end') - F('projects__design_start')),
            output_field=DurationField()),
            )    
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.DashView.as_view(), name='home'),
    ]
```

**index.html**

```
<h4>{{ design_time.design_time }}</h4>
```

Comment: `design_time` is a `QuerySet` hence there is no `design_time.design_time`, you need to _loop_ over it...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for your reply. I tried this: ```{% for time in design_time %}{{ time }} {% endfor %}``` and I got this error: *'You cannot use Sum, Avg, StdDev, and Variance '
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: You cannot use Sum, Avg, StdDev, and Variance aggregations on date/time fields in sqlite3 since date/time is saved as text.*

Comment: I have edited my answer for that error, do check.

Answer (score 1):

In your view you write:

```
context['design_time'] = Portfolio.objects.all().annotate(design_time=...)
```

Here your choice of the key is not very descriptive (even you were tricked by this name of yours it seems). Here `design_time` is a `QuerySet` of `Portfolio` objects, hence there is no such thing as `design_time.design_time`. Instead if you loop over `design_time` you will get `Portfolio` instances which will have `design_time` annotated onto them. To be more descriptive first rename this key in the context to something like:

```
context['portfolios'] = Portfolio.objects.all().annotate(design_time=...)
```

Next in your template loop over this:

```
{% for portfolio in portfolios %}
    {{ portfolio.design_time }}
{% endfor %}
```

Also in your query you use the `ExpressionWrapper` on the `Sum`, instead you should use `Sum` on the `ExpressionWrapper`:

```
Portfolio.objects.all().annotate(
    design_time = Sum(
        ExpressionWrapper(
            F('projects__design_end') - F('projects__design_start'),
            output_field=DurationField()
        )
    )
)
```